# How to use async and await in Angular to wait for a function to finish before executing the remainder of the function?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

I am trying to upload images before saving a record to a DB. I need the upload to finish before the record is saved:

The function responsible for the image upload:

```
  async uploadTrainingModule(selectedFiles: any = this.files) {
    // Perform Image Upload
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      await this.filesUploaded.push(selectedFiles[i]);
    }
  }
```

Using async and await in the above method, I hoped to allow the method to complete before executing anything else in the below method (this is the method responsible for writing to the DB):

```
 createTrainingModule() {
    this.uploadTrainingModule().then(resp => {
        // Upload to DB code below
    })
  }
```

My goal is to execute the code below the comment only AFTER the uploadTrainingModule method had been fully completed, however, what I have done above does not work? What approach could I possibly take?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using `RxJS` functions, by the following steps:

- combine all the upload functions with one `Observable` using `forkJoin` and return it from `uploadTrainingModule`.
- `subscribe` to this `Observable` within your `createTrainingModule`, and do what you need within the `subscribe` method.

Your code should look like the following:

```js
import { forkJoin, from, Observable } from "rxjs";

uploadTrainingModule(selectedFiles: any = this.files): Observable<any> {
  // Perform Image Upload
  // `forkJoin` will return one Observable once all the inner Observables (generated from promises using RxJS's `from` function) have been completed
  return forkJoin(
    selectedFiles.map((file) => from(this.filesUploaded.push(file)))
  );
}

createTrainingModule() {
  this.uploadTrainingModule().subscribe((resp) => {
    // Upload to DB code below
  });
}
```

Comment: With the above suggestion, only one image is uploaded (multiple can be uploaded at a single time), and as a result I get the following error: "ERROR TypeError: You provided '1' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.", what could be the reason for this?

Comment: What is the return type of this method `this.filesUploaded.push`, please?

Comment: this.filesUploaded is an array of files - i.e a FileList, each time it loops within the for loop, it is adding another file.

Comment: So, where is the `async` process with pushing the `file` to an array?
When is the real upload request happening?

Comment: Initially the files are selected, these files are then pushed to an array of FileList. The user then clicks on an upload button, and the method "createTrainingModule" is called. Due to "createTrainingModule" being called, the FileList array 'filesUploaded' is populated with the files that were in the initial FileList array (on selection of the files). Now that the array 'filesUploaded' is populated, I run an ngfor over the selector of a child component  over each file in the array (that child component being the component that holds the actual method for uploading the file).

Comment: So there is no need for `async` here, you can remove `async` and `await` and `then` from your code, and after `uploadTrainingModule` is called, you can directly do what you want within `createTrainingModule` method.

Comment: The issue is, I need to call `uploadTrainingModule` and `createTrainingModule`, and only after `uploadTrainingModule` is complete. should the code within `createTrainingModule` execute. So I need to have something in place to wait for `uploadTrainingModule` to finish?

Comment: No need for that because `uploadTrainingModule` is not doing any `async` process.
You can simply add any code after it, and it will not be executed until `uploadTrainingModule` is finished.